# correct way to run a sample CUDA application?

Tags: cuda

I am trying to launch the sample cuda application `vectorAdd` on Ubuntu 16.04 ARM. I go to the directory with `.cu` file and run `sudo make` followed by `./vectorAdd`. The result is

```
[Vector addition of 50000 elements]
Copy input data from host memory to CUDA device
CUDA kernel launch with 196 blocks and 256 threads
Copy output data from CUDA device to the host memory
Test PASSED
Done
```

Is this the correct way to run this application? If yes, why am I unable to input two sample vectors data and see the output like in regular C or C++ programs? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: because that is the way the sample code is written.  If you're a programmer, you could easily go in and modify the code to behave the way you suggest.  Anyway, your method of running the code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think the sample as a "enter your vectors via `std::cin`" program: the vectors are generated at runtime and their values do not even matter as long as the GPU sums them correctly

```
// Initialize the host input vectors with random values
for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
{
    h_A[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    h_B[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
}
```

The result is later verified on the CPU as well.

> Is this the correct way to run this application?

Yes it is, conforming to what I just wrote.

Comment: Is there a way I can check if the result is verified or does the `Test PASSED` line itself corresponds to the verfication?

Comment: @sam: you could just read the code instead of asking questions here

Comment: @sam Read the source code: it prints `Test PASSED` if the CPU validation succeeded.